# Changing session.save_path in php.ini not working

Tags: php, apache-2.4, .htaccess, php.ini, session

Fedora 25 + PHP 7 + Apache 2.4.23

Hello, after I change session.save_path in php.ini and restart apache, I can successfully verify that it's modified with:

`$ php -i | grep session.save_path`

However, in the html/php pages themselves, the sessions are not written so the session.save_path I set, but they're stubbornly written to /var/lib/php/session/. Even setting the value in .htaccess isn't working:

`php_value session.save_path "/mycustom/path/folder"`

The only working solution that can override the default /var/lib/php/session/ is to set the value in the php file itself:

`ini_set('session.save_path','/mycustom/path/folder');`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

1. create phpinfo() file in dir with this php file.
2. open it via browser, and find list of applied ini-files.
3. check all of these files to contain session.save_path override

Comment: Ah, that trick opened my eye on a little detail. In fact, phpinfo() was indeed showing that session.save_path had a local value of `/var/lib/php/session` and a master value of `/var/www/html/session` (my override in php.ini). I read that local values override master values http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520744/what-is-the-difference-between-local-value-and-master-value, so I checked all the php.d files and none had any overrides. BUT, running a `grep -R "session.save_path" /etc/httpd` and bingo, the override was coming from `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf`.

Comment: Looks like the server I was working on runs `php-fpm` which is a separate service running php and needs to be restarted (or reloaded) for ini changes to take effect in apache.

Comment: Thank you @synkro it help me to solve my issue as well